# Does Electron support pausing on uncaught exception during debugging?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, google-chrome-devtools, electron, inspect

When I try to use this feature in both DevTools (chrome:///inspect) and VSCode, it doesn't pause at the location of the error in my own code, but rather the main.js file inside the default app that is bundled with electron that tries to load my modules:

[image]

Source: https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/default_app/main.js#L291

I've also tried this with the [quick-start app](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start) and found the same issue... is there a way I can pause on uncaught exceptions in my own code?

Electron version: 1.8.2 (node 8.2.1)

OS: Windows 7

Command: `electron --inspect-brk .`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised/remembered that Electron has an initialisation phase which gets signaled via the `app.ready()` handler, so only uncaught exceptions raised *after* this completes successfully will pause execution in my main process code.

For now, I've modified `Module._load` in `electron/dist/resources/default_app.asar/main.js` to run outside of the try/catch block during `--inspect` so I can keep my ES module loading synchronous.